# Pushing XML elements except one into a second level in XSL without hard-coding element names

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have below XML input.

```
<value>
  <UniqueId>160052-ASDF</UniqueId>
  <ShipmentId>160052</ShipmentId>
  <PickListNo>160052_1</PickListNo>
</value>
```

The output I need is below.

`<value>` and `<UniqueID>` tags are always present.
Other tags vary for different messages.
Those needs to be enclosed within a `<Payload>` tag.

```
<value>
  <UniqueId>160052-ASDF</UniqueId>
  <Payload>
    <ShipmentId>160052</ShipmentId>
    <PickListNo>160052_1</PickListNo>
  </Payload>
</value>
```

Created following XSL, but I need a generic solution without hard-coding XML tags, other than `<value>` and `<UniqueID>` tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"       xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <value>
    <UniqueId>
      <xsl:value-of   select="/value/UniqueId"/>
    </UniqueId>
    <Payload>
      <ShipmentId>
        <xsl:value-of   select="/value/ShipmentId"/>
      </ShipmentId>
      <PickListNo>
        <xsl:value-of   select="/value/PickListNo"/>
      </PickListNo>
    </Payload>
  </value>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Tried using something like below, but no luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <value>
    <UniqueId>
      <xsl:value-of   select="/value/UniqueId"/>
    </UniqueId>
    <Payload>
      <xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::UniqueId)]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Payload>
  </value>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Your attempt would work if you changed `<xsl:for-each select="*[not(self::UniqueId)]">` to `<xsl:for-each select="value/*[not(self::UniqueId)]">`. Not that I think it's a good approach overall.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I think you are right, this is not a good and robust solution. I am not very good with XSL, so just gave it a try. Thanks again.

Comment: It's robust enough, just not as elegant as it could be. There's no need to recreate something that can be copied. And no need to individually copy each node in a selection, when you can just copy the entire selection at once (both shown in michael.hor257k's answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use e.g.

```
  <xsl:template match="value">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="UniqueId"/>
      <xsl:where-populated>
        <Payload>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="* except UniqueId"/>
        </Payload>
      </xsl:where-populated>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

The `xsl:mode` and `xsl:where-populated` is XSLT 3, the current version and generally supported version of XSLT; if you are stuck with XSLT 2 replace the `xsl:mode` with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and the `xsl:where-populated` with `<xsl:if test="* except UniqueId">`.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I have to stick with XSLT 2, and was able to resolve my problem using your solution. Much obliged..!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/value">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="UniqueId"/>
        <Payload>
            <xsl:copy-of select="* except UniqueId"/>
        </Payload>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. Just tried this and it worked as well..!